# Populating value using Array

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

```
var AppArray = [{
        Col1: 'asas', Col2:'12'
      },
      {
        Col1: 'asas2', Col2:'12'
      }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need this as an array if you have only one object in it.

you can just create an object itself instead of array and use it directly as `PrimeObj.col1` and `PrimeObj.col2`.

```
var PrimeObj = {col1: 'bsbbsb', col2:'30042'};
```

Comment: Can you update the code above to like that... it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: @theJava - Sorry, I did not get you. What code do you want me to update and what are you expecting as output or result?

Comment: I have updated my code, the output is i need a single label and textbox to be created using the new Array without going into loop

Comment: @theJava - yep. First your PrimeArray should be an object as I have defined in my answer. After that, you can use `PrimeArray.col1` to set value. Also beware, it is case-sensitive.

Comment: I did like that, but still nothing happens... what should be the value of data for PrimetableViewSettings ... updated the code also

Comment: @theJava - I think your `data:` accepts and array. hence declare `var rowData2 = []; rowData2.push(PrimeRow);`. Then initiate your `data:rowData2`.

Comment: Nothing shows up... i am not getting any error... updated the code again as per what you told

Comment: @theJava - you are getting output for value from `PrimeObj.Col1` right? Can you check that first? I am not sure what you are trying to do with PrimeViewSettings var anyway.

Comment: @theJava - It seems to be object of type `tableViewRow`.